# If $0<a<b$ and $0<c<d$ then $bd+ac>bc+ad.$ Can this inequality be generalised to include more than just two lots of two numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-writing, real-numbers, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

$0.7<2.4,\ $ and $\ 0.8< 0.9.$ By calculation, we see that $0.7\times 0.8 + 2.4\times 0.9 > 0.7\times 0.9 + 2.4\times 0.8.$

Indeed, for any pair of two numbers $\ 0<a<b\ $ and $\ 0<c<d,\ $ we have $\ (b-a)d>(b-a)c,$ and so $\ bd+ac>bc+ad.\quad (1)$

Can this inequality be generalised to include more than just two lots of two numbers? Let me elaborate.

Suppose we have an array of **positive** real numbers, where each row is ordered from largest to smallest:

$$
\begin{array}{}
a_{11} & > &a_{12} & > & \ldots & > & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & > &a_{22} & > & \ldots & > & a_{2n}\\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
a_{k1} & > &a_{k2} & > & \ldots & > & a_{kn}\\
\end{array}
$$

We choose **one entry from each row**, multiply these numbers together, remove them from the above array, then repeat this process. For example, if $\ n=3\ $ and $\ k=4,\ $ one possible outcome could be:

$$a_{11}\times a_{23}\times a_{31}\times a_{42} + a_{12}\times  a_{21}\times a_{32}\times a_{41} + a_{13}\times a_{22}\times a_{33}\times a_{43}\quad (2)$$

where $\ \times$ just means standard multiplication.

$(2)\ $ is one way of choosing the sum of the products if $\ n=3\ $ and $\ k=4.$ Indeed, there are many ways to choose the sum of products [the number of permutations could be an interesting combinatorics problem, but that is for another day...].

Now, I suspect the permutation [way of choosing the sum of products] that yields the **largest value** is:

$$ a_{11}\times a_{21}\times\ldots\times a_{k1}\ +\ a_{12}\times a_{22}\times\ldots\times a_{k2}\ + \ldots\ +\ a_{1n}\times a_{2n}\times\ldots\times a_{kn}.\quad (3) $$

Certainly, if we swap two entries in the above, for example, to get:

$$ a_{11}\times a_{2n}\times\ldots\times a_{k1}\ +\ a_{12}\times a_{22}\times\ldots\times a_{k2}\ + \ldots\ +\ a_{1n}\times a_{21}\times\ldots\times a_{kn}.\quad (4)$$

then $\ (4)\ $ will be less than $\ (3)\ $ because of the result $\ (1).$ But for two or more swaps, I think it will become either messy or simply not possible to use $\ (1)\ $ in a proof.

I was thinking Cauchy- Schwarz might be relevant, but I'm not sure. But yeah, I'm not sure if the result is true and if it is, how to go about proving it.

Comment: The $k = 2$ case is simply the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality), and I suspect the general case would be easy to prove by induction.

Comment: @ Connor Harris Thank you- I wasn’t aware of that inequality.